# how to access json variable from view into controller in asp.net 5

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc

learning asp.net 5.
I have following code in controller and view files. I have declared a javascript/json variable in index view file and I am trying to assign that variable to ViewData in HomeController.cs file. I am displaying ViewData value again in index view. Getting error in HomeController.cs file as json variable is not getting recognized.

```
HomeController.cs
-------------------
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;

    namespace EmptyAspDotNet.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
             public IActionResult Index()
            {
                ViewData["message"] = ParaString.message;
                return View();
            }        
        }
    }

Index.cshtml
--------------    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Empty Project taking shape</title>
        <script>
           var ParaString = { "message": "Welcome to this project" };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>@ViewData["message"]</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Javascript is client side code. You cannot assign a javascript value to `ViewData` (which is server side code) unless you send the value to the controller (e.g. using ajax)

Comment: Your action method gets executed first before executing the razor view. . Do you really need the variable value in the action method ? If you just want to display in the same view, simply use a C# variable and use that

Comment: thanks for your comments. I was trying to explore asp.net and that led me here. is there any way where I can declare json globally? can I declare json var in controller?

Comment: I am not pretty sure what is your aim but you cannot do that (declare js variable) in controller, but it is possible to pass data from controller (e.g. model, ViewData, ViewBag) to view and then you can assign them to some javascript variable like this `<script> var myvar = @Model.Value; </script>`.